# How to invoke a controller method just when condition happens

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I want to invoke controller method, in case a specific condition happens.

Can you give me an example how to implement it?

i guess it can intercepted with webapi filters..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are talking about invoking a method from a controller/api from another method/controller. It's actually pretty easy.

First, in your startup class you'll need to find the ConfigureServices method and add:

```
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

Then, in whichever controller you need it, just create a new instance of that controller and you can call those methods. Assume you have api1 and you want to call a method from api2. I'd create the api via dependency injection:

```
public class api1
{
    public _api2 {get;set;}

    public api1()
    {
        _api2 = new api2();
    }
}
```

And now you can call your methods however you'd like from api2:

```
public IActionResult SomeCondition()
{
    if(!someCondition)
    {
        return _api2.YourMethod1();
    }
    else
    {
         return _api2.YourMethod2();
    }
}
```